# Does the Ilvermorny School have a sorting hat?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat

Many fans of the Harry Potter Universe are continuing to learn more and more about the wizarding world, as the world expands through new media content, including [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/ilvermorny-school-of-witchcraft-and-wizardry).

One of the more recent additions, *and by recent I mean in the past five years or so*, comes in the form of an American school called, Ilvermorny, which like Hogwarts, has four houses.

I'm sure, I like many people, have taken the Pottermore sorting quiz to see what Ilvermorny House they would belong to, but I was wondering if **in-universe** the induction to the houses is the same as Hogwarts? **Does Ilvermorny have their own sorting hat or do they come to be inducted by another [magical] process?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no sorting *hat* but their sorting ceremony is still based on magical selection. One assumes that much the same [legilimency-based magic](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-sorting-hat) is used.

> Marble statues of Isolt and James flank the front doors of Ilvermorny
> Castle. The doors open onto a circular room topped by a glass cupola.
> A wooden balcony runs around the room one floor above. Otherwise the
> space is empty except for four enormous wooden carvings representing
> the houses: the Horned Serpent, the panther Wampus, the Thunderbird
> and the Pukwudgie.
>
> While the rest of the school watches from the circular balcony
> overhead, **new students file into the round entrance hall. They stand
> around the walls and, one by one, are called to stand on the symbol of
> the Gordian Knot set into the middle of the stone floor. In silence
> the school then waits for the enchanted carvings to react. If the
> Horned Serpent wants the student, the crystal set into its forehead
> will light up. If the Wampus wants the student, it roars. The
> Thunderbird signifies its approval by beating its wings, and the
> Pukwudgie will raise its arrow into the air.**
>
> Should more than one carving signify its wish to include the student
> in its house, the choice rests with the student. Very rarely – perhaps
> once a decade – a student is offered a place in all four houses.
> Seraphina Picquery, President of MACUSA 1920 - 1928, was the only
> witch of her generation so honoured, and she chose Horned Serpent.
>
> <sub><sup>[Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry By J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny)</sup></sub>

Comment: So it's the team-selection mechanic from The Voice.